# Link in navigation bar doesn't send me to the next page, but disappears

Tags: html, css, navigationbar

I have a focus transition on it. Normally when I click somewhere else on the page it disappears, but when I click on one of the links in the dropdown menu it also disappears! How can I keep it visible until I click the button in the navigation bar again!?

CSS:

```
.nav-item:focus {
    background-color: #444;
}

.nav-item:focus ~ .nav-content {
    max-height: 400px;
    -webkit-transition:max-height 400ms ease-in;
    -moz-transition:max-height 400ms ease-in;
    transition:max-height 400ms ease-in;


}
```

Comment: Post a complete code example please.

Comment: @LogicLucas can you post the rest of your code?

Answer (score 0):

Is `.nav-item` a form element? Otherwise the selector `focus` won't work with it, you should then use javascript for that. In addition, you don't need this '~' in `.nav-item:focus ~ .nav-content`:

```
.nav-item:visited .nav-content {
    max-height: 400px;
    -webkit-transition: max-height 400ms ease-in;
    -moz-transition: max-height 400ms ease-in;
    transition: max-height 400ms ease-in;
}
```

Comment: It is a class element for a div